# Choose Relationship For Joined Reports

Tags: joined-reports

I'm trying to build a joined report showing information about cases and related contacts, but I can't get the report to choose the correct data.

Here's my data model:

```
                             Contact
                              /   \
                       Contacts   Cases
     [Contact.Main_Client__c]       [Case.Client__c]
              [custom lookup]       [custom lookup]
```

I want to build a report that is grouped by the main contact, with details listing all of the related contacts and all of the related cases.
(In other words, `HAVING Contact.Main_Client__c = Case.Client__c`)

```
Main Contact 1 ---------------------------------
   Sub Contact 1           |   Sub Case 1
   Sub Contact 2           |   Sub Case 2
   Sub Contact 3           |
```

However, whenever I try to make a joined report, it identifies the wrong contact relationships in the record types, basically `HAVING Contact.Id = Case.Client__c`, which doesn't get me the data I need.

**Is there a way to tell Salesforce which relationships to use for a joined report?**

My fallback would be to export all of the source data to Excel and use VLOOKUP to build the joined table, but I'd love to do this directly in Salesforce if possible!